# AWS GreenGrass check Topic in Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-iot-greengrass

I am currently fiddeling around with AWS GreenGrass and I have gone through most of the basic examples. Now the problem I have understanding how I would perform different actions in my lambda function depending on the MQTT topic it was triggered by. I could not really find a documentation on how to differentiate which topic triggered the function handler in my python script. The thing I am trying to build is a small controller for my sonos system which uses the following very basic topics:

```
sonos/play
```

Which just tries playing a certain song I hardcoded.

```
sonos/pause
```

Which should be pausing the system.

I know I could create several lambdas for each command but that seems pretty finicky. Can someone please explain how one would tackle this sort of issue?

Answer (score 3):

Based on this [dev guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/developerguide/lambda-functions.html), in your lambda you can get the topic from the context:

```
def get_input_topic(context):
    try:
        topic = context.client_context.custom['subject']
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error('Topic could not be parsed. ' + repr(e))
    return topic
```

```
action = get_input_topic(context).split('/')[-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't actually think this is possible. If you look at both of the `event` and `context` objects passed into your lambda function, neither of them contain the topic address.

What I have had to do is to have a separate lambda function to respond for messages for each MQTT topic.

Happy to be corrected if this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the client context in context object of the lambda handler. Don't think this is documented. But this should solve your ask.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create an AWS IoT Rule?

I faced a similar problem, as I have several AWS IoT Things and I didn't want to create hundreds of subscriptions and lambdas.

Add the following subscription in your GG group:

```
Source    | Target       | Topic
----------|--------------|---------------------
IoT Cloud | [xyz_lambda] | [xyz_lambda]/trigger
```

Then go to the **Act** section on AWS IoT and create a rule , with the following statement:

```
SELECT topic(2) as action, * from 'sonos/#'
```

The `topic(2)` function captures the second segment of the topic (see [AWS IoT SQL Reference - Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide//iot-sql-functions.html#iot-function-topic)). We rename it as `action`. The `*` captures the payload sent along with the `sonos/play` or `sonos/pause` message (if any).

Add an action to your rule that republishes the message to the `[xyz_lambda]/trigger` topic.

The JSON event sent to your lambda function handler will have the property `action`, followed by the JSON payload of the `sonos/play` or `sonos/pause` message:

```
{
  "action": "play",
  ...
}
```

or

```
{
  "action": "pause",
  ...
}
```

Hope this helps!